# How to make slick.js work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, slick.js

I have many sliders with navigation bar like this:

```
// default slider. user see that after reloading page
.col-md-12.default-view
    .single-item
      - item_images(@item, :medium).each do |img|
        %div
          = image_tag img
    .col-md-12.images-nav
      - item_images(@item, :thumb).each do |img|
        .preview
          = image_tag img
// hidden sliders
- @item.colors.each do |c|
    .col-md-12.selected-view{class: "selected_preview_#{c.id}"}
      .single-item
        - c.images.each do |img|
          %div
            = image_tag img.pic.url(:medium)
        %div
          = image_tag @item.main_pic.url

      .col-md-12.images-nav
        - c.images.each do |img|
          .preview
            = image_tag img.pic.url(:thumb)
        .preview
          = image_tag @item.main_pic.url(:thumb)
```

My goal is show only one slider which can be selected via select tag(actually this part works fine). And problem is a weird behavior when user trying to select needed slider.

For example:

- user going to the page with those sliders
- and he/she can see normal work of slider and navigation bar
- after selecting color(via select tag), user can see normal work of slider and broken navigation bar

default slider:
[image: default slider]
and broken slider:
[image: selected slider]

For initializing slick.js I use this code(yeah, I know about DRY):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.default-view .single-item').slick({
    fade: true,
    prevArrow: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left col-md-1"></i>',
    nextArrow: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right col-md-offset-12"></i>',
    asNavFor: '.default-view .images-nav'
  });
  $('.default-view .images-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.default-view .single-item',
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true
  })
  $('.selected-view').each(function(){
    console.log(this);
    $(this).children('.single-item').slick({
      fade: true,
      prevArrow: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left col-md-1"></i>',
      nextArrow: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right col-md-offset-12"></i>',
      asNavFor: $(this).children('.images-nav')
    });
    $(this).children('.images-nav').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: $(this).children('.single-item'),
      arrows: false,
      centerMode: true,
      focusOnSelect: true
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Add your code please..

Comment: nvmd. I'm not working with frontend anymore :)